# lowest denominator to lie between two rational numbers

Tags: number-theory, rational-numbers

What's the lowest $ m\in \mathbb {N} $ such that the exists an $ n $ with $1/3 >\frac {n}{m}>33/100$? **note that there used to be a typo in the inequality which gives the opposite sign**

I'm on my phone so I can't really check duplicate,  so sorry if it happens to be (I feel it's very likely)

Comment: Impossible, right ? $33/100<1/3$.

Comment: Ooops I got the sign opposite around..

Comment: Why is my question downvoted so much..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be the desired quantity.  We have  $$\cfrac1{3+\cfrac1{33}} < x < \cfrac1{3+\cfrac1\infty}$$ so the continued fraction expansion of $x$ must be $$\cfrac1{3+\cfrac 1{n+y}}$$ where $33<n+y<\infty$. We get the smallest possible denominator by truncating the continued fraction after $n$ (taking $y=0$) and taking $n$ as small as possible, so $n=34$;  the answer is $$\cfrac1{3+\cfrac1{34}} = \frac{34}{103} \approx 0.330097.$$

Comment: Is there a solution that does not use continued fractions?  I don't really know about its theory.

Comment: Btw I changed the mistaken sign in the post

Comment: @WilsonofGordon Maybe instead of asking for a solution that doesn't use continued fractions, you should take the shortness of this solution, and the speed with which it arrived, as a sign that the theory of continued fractions is the right way to solve this kind of problem, and something you ought to find out about if you are interested in solving this kind of problem.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry, I don't understand what your point is.  I agree that $\frac{34}{102} = \frac13$.

Comment: Good point. I shall have a look at it,  I suppose it can solve all this kind of problems with the two give numbers replaced by any 2 rational numbers,  right? Is there a solution method if one or both are replaced by irrational numbers? @mjd

Comment: I mean, we can write the inequality as $34/103<34/102$, that's all - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The solution works the same way if the bounds are irrational.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That is a good point, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since OP has asked for a solution that does not involve the theory of continued fractions, I present this alternative solution which involves no theory whatsoever.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
      unsigned n, d;
      for (d=1; 1; d++) {
        for (n=1; n<d; n++) {
          double q = (double)n/d;
          if (33.0/100 < q && q < 1.0/3) {
            printf("%d / %d = %f\n", n, d, q);
            return 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The program exits almost instantly, after producing the output

```
    34 / 103 = 0.330097
```

Comment: This is awesome. .